# Building a dictionary

Tags: passwords, dictionary

I want to create a list of passwords to perform dictionary attack. Please show me how to build a password dictionary file. First, I gather information from users like hobbies, date of birth, favorite animals, etc. What should I do with this information?

Comment: You put that info together to create possible passwords and their variations, don't you? However, you might be reinventing the wheel, there should already be some good dictionaries, password databases, and related software.

Comment: Many, many resources online and tools for how to do this: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+password+dictionary which included the duplicate above